# python fmin optimize error (simplex downhill method)

Tags: python, fminsearch

I want to solve an fixpoint iteration with an fmin optimization.
I dont know why I get an Error like: 
     OVERFLOW ENCOUNTERS IN DOUBLE SCALAR:
I know the results and the first optimization before printing Status: 0
([ 2.85475105e-01  3.48080784e-01 -2.54628055e-04]) is right and the second value pair also. At the 3. optimisation loop the error appears..

I have just no idea what went wrong
Thanks for help.

```
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.optimize import fmin



dt = 0.001                  
t0 = 0                                                                     
tau = 4.0                                                                  
Steps = int(tau / dt)  + 1

def DGLS(t, Y0, Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4):

 return [(-Y0+alpha-Y0*Y4*(Y1/(1+mu2*Y2)+c)-phi*Y0*Y4*(Y2+c)-chi*Y0*Y4*(Y3+c)) ,
         (-Y1+nu*Y0*Y4/(1+mur*Y3)*(Y1/(1+mu2*Y2)+c)) ,
         (-Y2+phi*nu*Y0*Y4/(1+mur*Y3)*(Y2+c)/(1+mu1*Y1/(1+mu2*Y2))) ,
         (-Y3+chi*nu*Y0*Y4*(Y3+c)) ,
         (-Y4*(Y1+Y2+Y3))]


def RK4_end(DGLS, Startwert, Steps, t0, dt):

'''

   Runge Kutta Verfahren 4. Ordnung mit der Stepsize dt 
   Wiedergabe des letzten Wertes 

   Startwert ... im Array Startwert sind sind die Anfangswerte gespeichert
   Steps     ... Steps ist eine Zahl die der Iterationslänge entspricht um bis zum Maximalen Injektionstag in time zu rechnen

''' 

Y = np.zeros(5)

for t in range(t0 , Steps):
    if t == t0 :
        Y[0], Y[1], Y[2], Y[3], Y[4] = Startwert[0], Startwert[1], Startwert[2], Startwert[3], Startwert[4]

    k1 = DGLS( t , Y[0] , Y[1] , Y[2] , Y[3] , Y[4] )
    k2 = DGLS( t + 0.5 * dt , Y[0] + 0.5 * dt * k1[0] , Y[1] + 0.5 * dt * k1[1] , Y[2] + 0.5 * dt * k1[2] , Y[3] + 0.5 * dt * k1[3] , Y[4] + 0.5 * dt * k1[4] )
    k3 = DGLS( t + 0.5 * dt , Y[0] + 0.5 * dt * k2[0] , Y[1] + 0.5 * dt * k2[1] , Y[2] + 0.5 * dt * k2[2] , Y[3] + 0.5 * dt * k2[3] , Y[4] + 0.5 * dt * k2[4] )
    k4 = DGLS( t + dt , Y[0] + dt * k3[0] , Y[1] + dt * k3[1] , Y[2] + dt * k3[2] , Y[3] + dt * k3[3] , Y[4] + dt * k3[4] )


    Y[0] = Y[0] + (dt / 6.)*( k1[0] + 2.0 * k2[0] + 2.0 * k3[0] + k4[0] )
    Y[1] = Y[1] + (dt / 6.)*( k1[1] + 2.0 * k2[1] + 2.0 * k3[1] + k4[1] )
    Y[2] = Y[2] + (dt / 6.)*( k1[2] + 2.0 * k2[2] + 2.0 * k3[2] + k4[2] )
    Y[3] = Y[3] + (dt / 6.)*( k1[3] + 2.0 * k2[3] + 2.0 * k3[3] + k4[3] ) 
    Y[4] = Y[4] + (dt / 6.)*( k1[4] + 2.0 * k2[4] + 2.0 * k3[4] + k4[4] )

return Y
def calc(y):

  Startwert = np.array([10., y[0], y[1], y[2], 1.])

  solve = RK4_end(DGLS, Startwert, Steps, t0, dt)
  #print(solve[1],solve[2],solve[3],solve[4])
  return (solve[1]-y[0])**2 + (solve[2]-y[1])**2 + (solve[3]-y[2])**2


def main():

 accuracy = 1.0

 t1 = -5. * accuracy
 t2 = -5. * accuracy
 tr = -5. * accuracy

 T1v = []
 T2v = []
 Trv = []    

 T1 = []
 T2 = []
 Tr = []

 y = np.zeros(3)

 Status = 0
 while t1 < 0.1 * accuracy:

    while t2 < 0.1 * accuracy:

        while tr < 0.1 * accuracy:

            y[0] = 10**( t1 / accuracy )
            y[1] = 10**( t2 / accuracy )
            y[2] = 10**( tr / accuracy )

            simplex = fmin(calc, y , ftol=1E-15)
            print(simplex)

            if simplex[0]>0 and simplex[1]>0 and simplex[2]>0 and calc[y]<0.01:
                T1v.append(simplex[0])
                T2v.append(simplex[1])
                Trv.append(simplex[2])

            print(Status)
            Status = Status + 1

            tr = tr + 1

        tr = -5 * accuracy
        t2 = t2 + 1

    t2 = -5 * accuracy
    t1 = t1 + 1
```

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()

Comment: misses at the end, sry